# How to add counter using this method?

Tags: c#

```
case 3: // Record Daily Activity
    for (iOption = 3; iDayNum++;)
        Console.WriteLine("Record a Daily Activity"); //Lets the user know which option they selected.
```

I want the program to count a day each time Option 3 is selected but I am getting the following errors:

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'bool'
Use of unassigned local variable 'iDayNum'
```

Comment: the second value should be *boolean*, something like `for (iOption = 3; iDayNum++ < someValue;)`

Comment: Also, you have to assign some value to iDayNum before you start playing with it. Something like `iDayNum=0;`

Comment: Read [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: Please add some context. Why do you try to use a for loop?

Comment: Your for-loop lacks the condition part which is a boolean. 

    `for (initializer; condition; iterator)
        body`. What is the condition that ends the loop?

Comment: Have you tried searching for your two error messages? Their solution is normally the first search result. What is `iDayNum` supposed to be?

Comment: Post more code, we cant even see what variable the switch is using

Comment: Was my answer to your other question not helpful?

Answer (score 2):

Due to the lack of context in the question, I assume a lof of things here under. How about a simple increment?

```
//Initialization somewhere...
int iDayNum = 0;

switch(iOption)
{
    case 3:
        iDayNum++;
        Console.WriteLine("Record a Daily Activity");
        Break;
    default:
        Break;
}
```

Comment: This assumes that the switch is using `iOption`, also, both yours and my answer assumed that `iDayNum` exists which it wouldn't according to the op's second error

Comment: That's true, I implicitely thought that this problem was easy to understand >_< thanks for pointing it out.